Mhs 3.5 inch display trouble - screen rotation disabled?
Two days ago I started experimenting with Raspberry PI 4B and a 3.5 inch MHS display as described here:
http://www.lcdwiki.com/MHS-3.5inch_RPi_Display
I started, of course, by installing Raspberry PI OS. Unfortunately, I realized I didn't have a MicroHDMI cable, so I had to settle for VNC to start with. Thanks to this, I managed to connect remotely to Raspberry before I could even install the LCD driver.
Unfortunately, due to my ignorance, I started installing the driver for the Waveshare 3.5 inch display instead of MHS, then I simply formatted the SD card with Raspberry OS and installed everything again. Then I started working on the LCD driver for the MHS display according to the guide from the link a few lines above. And it installed.
You can control it via VNC and everything can be seen on the LCD, or control it on the LCD itself (touch works). However, it turns out that the screen rotation option is disabled.

From what I read on the Internet, it should be possible to set this:
a) Using the following commands - nothing changed for me:
cd LCD-show/
sudo ./rotate.sh 90

b) By reinstalling and setting the rotation at the very beginning - nothing changed
sudo rm -rf LCD-show
git clone https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git
chmod -R 755 LCD-show
cd LCD-show/
sudo ./MHS35-show

c) By getting into the config.txt file and trying to change this value "90";
this didn't change anything, so I also tried changing the name mhs to tft35a, and then mhs35 to piscreen,drm (To make sure that the manufacturer did not deceive me with the print on the silkscreen):
dtoverlay=mhs35:rotate=90
 # For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See lin>

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default >
#hdmi_safe=1

uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positi>
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much bor>
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

uncomment to force a console size. By default it will >
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composit>
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will for>
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

 uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This c>
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have inte>
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional >
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boo>

Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displ>
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB con>
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 con>
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is no>
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=mhs35:rotate=90
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 480 320 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=2

For now, the screen still doesn't rotate. Thanks to this, I always have the screen with the power cable facing down, which makes it difficult to place it normally. Is it possible that something has been messed with in the RPI settings since these reinstallations, that the screen rotation option is blocked, or am I just doing something else very wrong? I will be grateful for your help.
Regards
Karlsson

You haven't specified what OS you are using but the current kernels using kms DO NOT support the obsolete fkms settings.

Thanks for the reply. I use Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit) released 2024-03-15 with kernel: 6.6. Is this a suggestion that the solution might be to roll back to one of the older OS versions?

Definitely NOT. Lots of people do this but it is a dead end. You can set resolution in the GUI. If running headless there is an raspi-config option to set VNC resolution which I use on my Pi.

Ok, but why do you call it "obsolete fkms settings"? It would seem that the display rotation that I care about is something completely basic rather than obsolete. Unless the creators of the operating system want to systematically limit its customization options.

I was referring to the driver. Previously Pi used a driver in firmware - current OS use a kernel driver (like most Linux)which is more functional but can't be configured in firmware. It is still possible (at least for standard Pi at the moment) to use the firmware drivers if you are prepared to forego the performance advantages in  modern hardware. I am not sure if this is even possible with 64bit OS so you would probably need a 32 bit OS.
